# Videocapture problem with video and real-time

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have a problem. I made an application that can detect the heartbeat from the face. Its functioning is correct if I use videocapture (0) (therefore using the webcam of the machine), but the results are wrong if I use any recorded video.
I guess there are compatibility, codec or compression issues.
How could I solve?

Comment: How are you reading the video ?

Comment: videocapture("name video")... and everything else remains the same. also I see the video very accelerated, as if it read all the frames quickly. If i use videocapture(0) all work well..

Comment: "the results are wrong" how are they wrong? do you get an error message? you get no error but the result is different from what you expected? please, give details

Comment: Yes, the results are different from those expected. It is not a code problem as if I use videocapture (0) the results are correct. I noticed though that the videos running on opencv scroll very fast.

Comment: Try getting the frame-rate ([function here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939) and [property enum here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ggaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704daf01bc92359d2abc9e6eeb5cbe36d9af2)) then try to adjust WaitKey to match it.

Comment: My webm file don't have information about fps... i don't know why. But m getUserMedia and RecordRTC return a webm file withouth framerate information

Comment: With no sample input data, no code and no expected output, it's not that easy to provide any help.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV will read video files as quickly as possible. that's a feature.

if you need to display that data at a particular speed, it's your responsibility to throttle the loop. as suggested in the comments, you would do that by giving a suitable (maximum!) delay to `waitKey`.

if your VideoCapture object doesn't give a sensible value for CAP_PROP_FPS, see if you can get a sensible value for CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC.